# Perl script to generate Visual studio solution files and project files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perl

How can VS 2010 project files and solution files can be generated by perl script? Any link or any help is welcomed thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @CraigTreptow, "Any link or any help is welcomed". He or she is asking for a *start*, what's possible. WHYT does not fit every case.

Comment: @CraigTreptow if you read the link you have posted, you'll notice the quote "The problem is that this person’s problem-solving technique is to ask for the solution"  This question does not do that; making your link irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to identify which type of project you need. Specially the Programming Language to be used by those Templates.

There is a bunch of documentation in the MSDN site about Project templates such as:

Visual Studio Templates
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx

Creating Project and Item Templates
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx

If you have VS2010 installed you just need to go to the VS2010 Templates folder ( "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\" ) and take those files from your PERL script, build the folder structure of a project and paste those files once you do some STRING replacing on each of them.

For instance, the Console Application template in C# looks like:

- App.config
- assemblyinfo.cs
- consoleapplication.csproj
- csConsoleApplication.vstemplate
- program.cs

All the files are plain text so you should be able to read/replace from them from your perl script.

And the folder structure once VS2010 creates it is:

- bin
- obj
- Properties

  - AssemblyInfo.cs
- *.csproj
- Program.cs

So, you have to create the folder structure and copy the files.

With that I believe now is just a matter of creating the Perl script to handle all that above.

Hope that helps